# Android path to array - read the points on a path?

Tags: android, path

Is there a way to read the points created when drawing a path? It seems silly to me that a path cannot be readable.

Or is it just better to manually write the current finger position to an array?

thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can read as many points as you want from any path.
Example how to read coordinates from the middle of path:

```
    PathMeasure pm = new PathMeasure(myPath, false);
    //coordinates will be here
    float aCoordinates[] = {0f, 0f};

    //get coordinates of the middle point
    pm.getPosTan(pm.getLength() * 0.5f, aCoordinates, null);
```

You can pass any distance from the path start to get point coordinates.

Comment: pm.getPosTan(pm.getLength() * 0.5f, aCoordinates, null); returns boolean value then wehre is the point ???

Comment: @JhansiKiRani, he sais right there: //coordinates will be here. So in aCoordinates.

Comment: how do you get the points on a line that is drawn with a finger using this answers method? assume it isn't known but the start points are kept in `Path`

Comment: @dan Let's say you want 11 points (10 equal segments):

```
    // the begining:

    pm.getPosTan(pm.getLength() * 0.0f, aCoordinates, null);

    // 1st point:

    pm.getPosTan(pm.getLength() * 0.1f, aCoordinates, null);

    // 2nd point:
    pm.getPosTan(pm.getLength() * 0.2f, aCoordinates, null);
    // 3rd point:
    pm.getPosTan(pm.getLength() * 0.3f, aCoordinates, null);
    // etc
    // the last point
    pm.getPosTan(pm.getLength(), aCoordinates, null);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. So then the coordinates in aCoordinates will be changed to the corresponding distance then?

Comment: @dan Yes, `aCoordinates` will get coordinates of a corresponding point. This demo code uses a simple data type. It's up to you to use more appropriate type. And you're not limited to equal segments.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, I think that you can't get previously added points, but you can extend Path class and create your own, override add methods, and then store that points in an array or a list or whatever you prefer.

Comment: Thanks, that’s what I thought. I don’t think extending the class will add anything more than just adding the points (x, y) from onMyTouchEvent to an ArrayList instead.

Answer (score -1):

You mentioned finger position in your question. If you are drawing and using motion events, you could add the X and Y positions to an ArrayList during the event where all even indices are X's and odds are Y's. I used this in a couple of drawing apps I created. To recreate the path all you need is a for loop and Path.lineTo().

Also if you have drawn the path to a view with a specific color, say Color.Black, you can use Bitmap.getPixels(...) and create an array {x0,y0,x1,y1,....xn,yn} based off a for loop like

```
int i = 0;
for(int y = 0; y < bitmap.getHeight(); y++){
    for(int x = 0; x < bitmap.getWidth(); x++){
        if(pixels[y*bitmap.getWidth()+x] == Color.BLACK){
            xy[i] = x;
            i++;
            xy[i] = y;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

The array xy has all your coordinates.