# How do I find all the Points in a Path in Android?

Tags: java, android, path, point

Awhile back I asked a question to see if I was able to find a pair of specific points in a path; however, this time I want to know if there is a way to know all points in a path? (I couldn't find a method that did so, which is unfortunate because Java provides a way to do this, just not Android?)

The reason I ask this is because I have multiple geometric graphs and I want to compare the points to see where they intersect.

I appreciate any helpful responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have created a `Path` that means that in some point of your code, you know the exact (Geo)point. Why don't you put this point(s) on a `ArrayList` or something similar?

So for example before doing:

```
path.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
```

you can do:

```
yourList.add(point);
path.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
```

And later you can get all your points from the `ArrayList`.
Note you that you can take advantage of the [Enhanced For Loop Syntax](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html#foreach) of `ArrayList` that execute up to three times faster.

Comment: That was what I was going to do if there wasn't any alternative. I'll leave the question open for a few more days and if there is no other way suggested, I'll accept this as the answer.

Comment: @StartingGroovy Ok, see my updated post, in order to take advantage of a performance speedup, if you finally choose this solution.

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware that the enhanced for loop was 3 times faster :) thanks for that tidbit!

Comment: If you're carrying round a data structure with all your points in it, why would you need to have a Path object? Duplicating this data violates the DRY principle.

Comment: you don't have to know the points. For example if you obtain the path with android.graphics.Paint.getTextPath

Answer (score 42):

You can use `PathMeasure` to get coordinates of arbitrary point on the path.For example this simple snippet(that I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9103540/1043882)) returns coordinates of the point at the half of the path:

```
PathMeasure pm = new PathMeasure(myPath, false);
//coordinates will be here
float aCoordinates[] = {0f, 0f};

//get point from the middle
pm.getPosTan(pm.getLength() * 0.5f, aCoordinates, null);
```

Or this snippet returns an array of `FloaPoint`s.That array involves coordinates of 20 points on the path:

```
private FloatPoint[] getPoints() {
        FloatPoint[] pointArray = new FloatPoint[20];
        PathMeasure pm = new PathMeasure(path0, false);
        float length = pm.getLength();
        float distance = 0f;
        float speed = length / 20;
        int counter = 0;
        float[] aCoordinates = new float[2];

        while ((distance < length) && (counter < 20)) {
            // get point from the path
            pm.getPosTan(distance, aCoordinates, null);
            pointArray[counter] = new FloatPoint(aCoordinates[0],
                    aCoordinates[1]);
            counter++;
            distance = distance + speed;
        }

        return pointArray;
    }
```

In above snippet,`FloatPoint` is a class that encapsulate coordinates of a point:

```
class FloatPoint {
        float x, y;

        public FloatPoint(float x, float y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public float getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public float getY() {
            return y;
        }
    }
```

***References***:
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9103540/1043882)
[Animating an image using Path and PathMeasure – Android](http://c05mic.wordpress.com/2012/03/23/animating-a-bitmap-using-path-and-pathmeasure-android/)

Comment: You can also use the built in [PointF class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PointF)

Comment: I tried using this answer but getLength is producing 0.0 and therefore not entering the while loop that I have.
Here's the code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65039195/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-endpoints-of-a-line-when-using-path-class?noredirect=1#comment115115814_65039195
Would you have any idea as to why it produces 0.0?