# How to draw line in different patterns using canvas?

Tags: android, android-canvas

Hey I want to draw a line in different patterns by using canvas.

Any idea or suggestion are appreciate ..!!!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by pattern here?

Comment: Can you post the link of the application which does the same? Just to understand what you mean by net pattern?

Comment: Ok. So if you have any idea related to this then please share with me.

Comment: May this one help you. http://storage.dangertree.net/harmonyStrokes/harmony.html#curvy

Comment: **Refer my answer for [Drawing with pattern fills in canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41520998/4629101)**

Answer (score 3):

You have to use **[`Path`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CGAQFjAF&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html&ei=yU3wUOzJOZL-rAGEnYGYBA&usg=AFQjCNFMEZ0j2vjln4dbXsniIBM24yEKww&sig2=qnoGqNQra6gCQc55U1NbVQ&bvm=bv.1357700187,d.aWM)**.Docs say:

> The Path class encapsulates compound (multiple contour) geometric
>   paths consisting of straight line segments, quadratic curves, and
>   cubic curves. ...

For example,you can extend a `view` and add touch event positions to a `path` in `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` method of your view.Then you have to generate  random positions correspond to newest touch event and add their to other instances of path.Finally in `onDraw()` method of your view,draw all paths.I hope this snippet help you to understand my idea:

```
public class NetCanvas extends View {

    private static final double MAX_DIFF = 15;
    Path path0 = new Path();
    Path path = new Path();
    private Paint p0;
    private Paint p;

    public NetCanvas(Context context) {
        super(context);
        p0 = new Paint();
        p0.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 230, getHeight(), Color.GREEN,
                Color.RED, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
        p0.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

        p = new Paint();
        p.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 230, getHeight(), Color.BLUE,
                Color.MAGENTA, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
        p.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        float x0 = event.getX();
        float y0 = event.getY();
        float x = generateFloat(event.getX());
        float y = generateFloat(event.getY());

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            path0.moveTo(x0, y0);
            path0.lineTo(x0, y0);

            path.moveTo(x, y);
            path.lineTo(x, y);
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            path0.lineTo(x0, y0);

            path.lineTo(x, y);
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            path0.lineTo(x0, y0);

            path.lineTo(x, y);
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(path0, p0);
        canvas.drawPath(path, p);
    }

    private float generateFloat(Float f){
        double d = (Math.signum(2*Math.random() - 1)) * Math.random() * MAX_DIFF;
        return (float) (f + d);
    }
}
```

*In above code,I used two `path`s,but you can use three or **more***.Also the result,depends on your finger rate on the screen.For example:
[image]

or it may looks like this:

[image]

**Edit:**

Above class(`NetCanvas`) extends `View`,so you can create an instance of it and use that instance,like other views.For example,you can simply set an instance of it as `ContentView` of your Activity.Here I override `onCreate()` method of Activity:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new NetCanvas(this));
    }
```

*Although you can change `NetCanvas` to extend `SurfaceView` with some other changes.*

Comment: @mpp I added another answer,please see it.I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I changed `NetCanvas` to draw a shape look like second image in your question:

```
public class NetCanvas1 extends View {

    Path path0 = new Path();
    private Paint p0;
    private int points_Num = 20;
    private int first_Points_Num = 5;

    public NetCanvas1(Context context) {
        super(context);
        p0 = new Paint();
        p0.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 230, getHeight(), Color.GREEN,
                Color.RED, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
        p0.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        float x0 = event.getX();
        float y0 = event.getY();

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            path0.moveTo(x0, y0);
            path0.lineTo(x0, y0);

        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            path0.lineTo(x0, y0);
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            path0.lineTo(x0, y0);
            invalidate();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(path0, p0);
        FlaotPoint[] pointArray = getPoints();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < first_Points_Num; i++) {
                for (int j = i; j < pointArray.length; j++) {
                    canvas.drawLine(pointArray[i].getX(), pointArray[i].getY(),
                            pointArray[j].getX(), pointArray[j].getY(), p0);
                }
            }
            path0.reset();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    private FlaotPoint[] getPoints() {
        FlaotPoint[] pointArray = new FlaotPoint[points_Num];
        PathMeasure pm = new PathMeasure(path0, false);
        float length = pm.getLength();
        float distance = 0f;
        float speed = length / points_Num;
        int counter = 0;
        float[] aCoordinates = new float[2];

        while ((distance < length) && (counter < points_Num)) {
            // get point from the path
            pm.getPosTan(distance, aCoordinates, null);
            pointArray[counter] = new FlaotPoint(aCoordinates[0],
                    aCoordinates[1]);
            counter++;
            distance = distance + speed;
        }

        return pointArray;
    }

    class FlaotPoint {
        float x, y;

        public FlaotPoint(float x, float y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public float getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public float getY() {
            return y;
        }
    }
}
```

Result depends on values of `points_Num`, `first_Points_Num` and order of points that are connected with lines in for loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < first_Points_Num; i++) {
                for (int j = i; j < pointArray.length; j++) {
                    canvas.drawLine(pointArray[i].getX(), pointArray[i].getY(),
                            pointArray[j].getX(), pointArray[j].getY(), p0);
                }
            }
```

You can change value of each variable or order of points to change result.Result may be looks like these:

[image]   [image]

My idea is simple: ***Get points from path and connect them with lines***.If you want to see more details in about getting points from path,that is done in `getPoints()` method,you can see **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14346276/1043882)** and it's references.I *hope* this help you.

Comment: Very nice example but its not working smoothly.

Comment: Hey can you suggest me how can I use this same code by extending SurfaceView? Thanks.

Comment: @voidRy you can see [this tutorial](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Using-Surface-View-for-Android-1659.php#top).